# QstandardItem Model signal not emitted when changed programatically

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a `QStandardItemModel`. The model itself has two columns one is a text column and the other is a checkbox. Now I have a connection of the signal to a slot in my code as such

```
QObject::connect(model,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)),
this,SLOT(ColumnChecked(QStandardItem*))); //Column to filter checked
```

Now this signal works fine when the user makes a change in the Form. I.e when the user is using the form. However if I check a box from my code the signal is not emitted. For instance if I go like this:

```
model->item(i,1)->setCheckState(Qt::CheckState::Checked);
```

the slot is not called. So I have to go like this to call the slot after making the changes

```
Column_Model->item(i,1)->setCheckState(Qt::CheckState::Checked);    
ColumnChecked(Column_Model->item(i,1));
```

Could you tell me is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong. I was expecting the slot to be called even if I make changes to the model in code.

Comment: This is strange. Check that new check state is not the same as previous one. Check that `connect` statement is executed before `setCheckState`. Also I don't know what is `Qt::CheckState::Checked`. it's usually written as `Qt::Checked`, your code gives me a compile error.

Comment: Does `Qt::CheckState::Checked` generate the compiler error at your end ?

Comment: Yes: `error: 'Qt::CheckState' is not a class or namespace` (GCC 4.8)

Comment: I am pretty sure we could use enums as Qt::CheckState::Checked atleast in VS2010